# Membership cancelled, but active until end date

Tags: civimember

Our memberships period is a calendar year. If a member decides to cancel, he will still be a member until the end of the year. During the remainder of the year, the member can still profit from his membership. But he must not be reminded of renewing his membership.

So, the end date discriminates active memberships, not the membership status itself. At the end of the year, the status should still be cancelled, not expired.

Is this something that can be done?

Comment: How are you doing your reminders?

Answer (score 3):

I think I did a bit of both:

I created an extra membership status called Stopped. This is valid and active until the end of the year. At the end of the year I update all the Stopped memberships to Cancelled.

Comment: Sounds  good. thx for sharing back

Answer (score 1):

As you know, membership statuses are calculated based on membership status rules, however, the status of "Cancelled" can only be manually assigned, and it does not represent a "current" membership. You might want to consider creating a new rolling, monthly membership type (e.g. "Cancelling") with no "auto-renew" option that will keep members current for the remainder of the period - this will allow you to exclude this membership type from receiving scheduled reminders for renewal and to quickly search for and update the membership statuses to "Cancelled" when their end date has been reached (using update multiple membership records as described [**HERE**](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/renewals/#update-multiple-memberships)). In short, you would cancel their existing membership, then create a new "Cancelling" membership with an end date that matches the existing membership.

Important: If you have any discounts/permissions based on membership type, you'll need to be sure to add the "Cancelling" membership type to the list of eligible memberships.

Hope this helps!,
Tamar

Answer (score 1):

Something like following might work
- add an Activity for those who no longer wish to be members
- make a smart group of the above
- exclude the Smart Group from getting Scheduled Reminders about renewing
- on d-day find Smart Group and batch update Membership status to Cancelled.